# Windows 7 stuck in startup logo after i instal my new GPU gforce 210 nvidia can anyone help me

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, motherboard, bios, gpu

I have Chinese motherboard
zx I945lm vr 1.4 I
Bios ver 080014 ami update 2009
I installed my Gpu and I turn on my pc that have wind 7 so it start normal till show windows logo and is stuck I used safe mode and no result I update gpu bios no result but when I take GPU off from motherboard and I switch bios adapter to PCI /PEG
Its start normal please help me
Should I update bios if yes please let know how can I found it because I'm tired looking for it but no results

Comment: If you use safe mode without any issue, I would suspect system did load the correct GPU driver when Windows boot up. Because safe mode will not use third party vendor driver and only load Windows system build-in driver. So go to graphic website and download Windows 7 compatibility driver to check.

Answer (score 0):

Go to troubleshoot it:

- Do your Video card (GPU) have a power port that you don't connect to?
- Is your previous GPU (onboard or not) is nVidia?
- Did you try to install your new GPU driver first and then try to install the GPU to it?

If your GPU card has like power port, that is must be plugged on otherwise the GPU card can't working as it should and could be turned off.

If your previous card isn't Nvidia probably driver conflict, uninstall the previous video driver first.

If 2 of that you did it but it still not working, try to install first hand the driver for the new GPU and go install it.

If all of that didn't work, try to make sure your card is really working fine. Try to another computer.